# Couldn't open shared file mapping error in Pytorch Dataset

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error, dataloader

When training a model using a custom dataset in Pytorch 1.4 the following error is thrown after a seemingly random amount of epochs.

```
RuntimeError: Couldn't open shared file mapping: <torch_15324_2327643205>, error code: <1455>
```

The dataset is wrapped in a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` and uses 4 workers, equal to the amount of physical cores.

```
class TSNDataSet(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, pickle_file_paths, transforms):
        self.pickle_file_paths = pickle_file_paths # list with file paths to pickle files
        self.dataset_size = len(pickle_file_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        with open(self.pickle_file_paths[index], 'rb') as f:
            mffs = pickle.load(f)
            
        return mffs, index

    def __len__(self):
        return self.dataset_size
```

It would be helpful to know what the error means and what the possible solutions are.

Comment: May be relevant: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/couldnt-open-shared-file-mapping/8403

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I've run into it too.

Answer (score 0):

Very possibly it happens when GPU memory is getting close to be exhausted. Same problem was observed after every next epoch started. I ran excerpt of ImageNet with 1300 batch size, using 1070Ti with 8GB of memory. Images were loaded from RAM drive.

The problem was related to *collate* operations performed by *torch.utils.data.DataLoader* on *enumerate* call.

For attached screenshot, my failures occurred when graph showed red line and shared memory was 14+ GBytes in use. After batch size was reduced twice, to 650, Task Manager shows mere 2.6 GB in use, and program runs just fine, from epoch to epoch.

- Project: "imagenet" from official PyTorch [examples](https://github.com/pytorch/examples.git).
- Images: ILSVRC2012\train and var, first 69 folders from full set,
  1300 images per folder.
- IDE: PyCharm 2023.3.3 Community
- Python: 3.10.4

[image: Task Manager (Windows 10)]